# Strange Chinese characters mixed with English in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I got strange Chinese characters whenever I try to install packages. For instance:

> installing the source package 態H

I tried to searched this online and found a solution that says I can change the option, i.e. `options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE)`

This works perfectly. However, this only solve the problem temporarily, and those strange Chinese characters will show up again next time when I write a new program and install packages. So, I wonder if there's a way to solve this problem permanently? Can I do something so that the R will run `options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE)` automatically? Or, are there any other permanent solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you run: `Sys.getlocale()`?

Comment: The Sys.getlocale() gives me this:"LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"